# Testing variable throwing errors

Tags: python, variables

I'm working on a lab testing software - I'm at the backbone stage, and I'm just trying to test if the emergency stop will recognize a failure before it gets too far along.

Here is the code:

```
import sys

def main(argv):
    currentTempAverage = 0;
    testingPlaced = False
    typeOfTesting = False
    issue="False"
    class labTesting(object):

def __init__(self,currentCondition,emergencyStop=0):
    self.output = labLog()
Conditions = []
    self.status = "OPEN"
    self.beginningCondition = currentCondition
    self.EndingCondition = ""
    self.output.log("Testing opened")

if float(currentCondition) > float(self.beginningCondition*1.003):
    issue="True"

if (issue=="True") and float(currentCondition) < float(beginningCondition*1.002):
        self.output.log("YIKES!")
        self.status="CLOSED"

    if (emergencyStop):
        self.emergencyStop = currentCondition - emergencyStop
    self.output.log("stop loss") 

def close(self,currentCondition):
    if currentCondition > (self.beginningCondition * 1.012717049):
        self.status = "CLOSED"
        self.EndingCondition = currentCondition

def tick(self, currentCondition):




def showTesting(self):
    testingStatus = "Entry Condition: "+str(self.beginningCondition)

    self.output.log(testingStatus)
```

Basically, it's checking levels, and if the levels reach a certain point - issue=true, because it may become an issue.

If the levels become lower, it does the emergency stop.  Depending how I do it, it throws errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/DDesm/Desktop/w/labtest/testing.py", line 18, in tick
    if (issue=="True") and float(currentPrice) < float(entryPrice*1.002):

     UnboundLocalError: local variable 'issue' referenced before  assignment
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have this line  `class labTesting(object):` in  `main()` and the indentation is off.

Comment: The problem here is that if your first condition isn't met, the variable `issue` hasn't been defined. When your write `issue=false` in `main`, that variable exists only within the scope of the function `main` so isn't accessable outside that function, until it has been defined elsewhere.

Comment: Your code is poorly indented, and incomplete.

Comment: The indention is off because I use a text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have inside `main` you probably just want to be ran at the top of the program. Even if you did run `main`, those variables would only be instantiated locally. Thus, `issue` can only possibly be instantiated (as well as being set to "True" at:

```
if float(currentCondition) > float(self.beginningCondition*1.003):
    issue="True"
```

As an aside, Python does have boolean values. You can just do `issue = True`, and then the if statement can be simplified to just `if issue ...`.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all, you are referencing `issue` before you assigned it.
**Break down:**

In `main` you defined issue however, the comparison is taking place inside the `__init__` method of a class. In the scope of the `__init__` method, issue is not defined. You can over come this by passing `issue` to the `__init__` method like follows:

```
def __init__(self,currentCondition,issue,emergencyStop=0):
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't fully understand where you're coming from. Can you elaborate?

Comment: `issue` does not exist inside the `__init__` method where it is called. Pass issue into the `__init__` method, then it will  exist there (it will be assigned) and you can reference it.